# How to set <html lang> dynamically for different pages in SvelteKit?

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit, lang

In my SvelteKit app, some pages are in English (`en`) and some pages are in Farsi (`fa`).
The `app.html` file sets the `lang` attribute to `en` statically for the entire app.
How can I make the `lang` attribute dynamic and set it to a different value for different pages depending on the language of the page?"

I tried to bind the `lang` attribute to a dynamic value using `lang={lang}` in the `app.html` file, but this did not work because variables cannot be used in the `app.html` file in the same way they can be used in `.svelte` files.

Answer (score 2):

Server [hooks](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks) are what you're looking for, you can check whether or not you're on an English or Farsi page from the hook event object. Assuming you're using TypeScript this is approximately what the `src/hooks.server.ts` file will look like.

```js
export const handle = (async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  let lang = event.url.startsWith('/fa') ? 'fa' : 'en';
  return resolve(event, {
    transformPageChunk: ({ html }) => html.replace('%lang%', lang)
  });
}) satisfies Handle;
```

This is the recommended way of injecting values in the HTML that's usually inaccessible to Svelte. There's actually a [closed issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/3091#issuecomment-1112589090) about this on the official SvelteKit repo.